# failed to set up the execution context to run test (native c++ unit test) vs2015

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dll, dllexport

I have created a win32 dll project i was exporting my functions from dll without encapsulating them and i have written their unit test and every thing was going smooth until I have added an export class to start encapsulating my function with in a class the compilation and build succeed *also using the dll in another win32 console application succed* but when i try to run the new unit test added it throw an error **Failed to set up the execution context to run test**
and also the other test in the project fails with the same error however before adding the exported class all test's passes.
to keep in mind I didn't change anything in my project setting.

dllEntryPoint header.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void someFunction();

class __declspec(dllexport) myClass{
      public:
          myclass();
 };
```

unit Test class

```
TEST_METHOD(myTestMethod)
{
    myClass* newClass = new myclass();
}
TEST_METHOD(mySecondTestMethod)
{
    someFunction();
}
```

before adding myclass to the dll header file the `mySecondTestMethod` was passing the unit test but after adding the exported class all the unit test are failing with the same above error.

also I have read so many solution for this problem but its not working, so any one fall in this case and found a way to solve it?